# How to index Firestore data into Algolia using cloud functions if a user creates a new document?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

**Requested behaviour:** 
I would like to create a cloud function which adds a new entry to an Algolia index every time a user creates a new document in Firestore.

**Current State** 
The cloud function successfully gets triggered if a user creates a new document. However, the function does not create a new entry to the Algolia index.

**issue** 
Instead, it throws a firestore console error which I do not understand. The function does not throw any additional ts-lint errors.

> What does the error mean and how can I fix it? Do I handle
>   the document ID correctly or is there an issue with the Algolia configuration?

**My code:**

```js
// importing libaries

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';


// setting up environment

const ALGOLIA_APP_ID = 'my-app-id';
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = 'my-admin-key';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// Call onCreate to add data to ALgolia Index

export const ideaIndexAdd = functions.firestore
  .document('ideas/{ideaID}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
  
    const data = snap.data();
    const objectID = snap.id;
    const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);
    const index = client.initIndex('ideas');

    // Add the data to the algolia index
    return index.addObject({
      objectID,
      ...data
    });
});
```

**The firestore console error**

```html
AlgoliaSearchNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND azrzbvfkpr-2.algolianet.com azrzbvfkpr-2.algolianet.com:443
    at ClientRequest.error (/user_code/node_modules/algoliasearch/src/server/builds/node.js:233:14)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:324:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1034:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your Firebase project is on the free Spark plan, which does not support networking out to endpoints that are not fully controlled by Google.  You will have to upgrade your project to a paid plan if you want to connect to services outside of Google.

Comment: Oh, I am still noncommercial and training my programming skills. Two quick questions: I wanted to use Algolia to make a firestore string field (for idea titles) searchable. Do you know if thats possible by only using firestore queries? I read that sql queries like `like %ideaTitle%` are not possible. Besides that: Is the code correct?

Comment: Please post separately for additional questions.  Please ask only one question per post, otherwise it may get closed for being too broad.